# AzureAD (OpenID) authentication to replace FormsAuthentication

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

We have a complex, a decade old corporate CRM system that is built in AngularJS, Asp.Net MVC, Entity Framework and .Net Api. It implements FormsAuthentication where users are authenticated with username/ password stored in Db.

I have recently joined this company and I have tasked to replace this FormsAuthentication with secure Azure AD authentication (MFA). The catch is the users are still have the local Db configured. After getting redirected from Azure authentication, the user data is loaded from local Db. Azure AD only authenticates the users, the other user based permissions and access levels are still loaded from Db. Now with FormsAuthentication it was easier where we stored the encrypted user data in FormaAuthentication Ticket/ Cookie which persists across session.

I have been able to integrate Azure AD in current System. FormsAuthentication is disabled. The users are being authenticated, redirected from Azure using OpenIDConnect endpoint. My main problem is now how to persists the user data from Db as there is no FormsAuthenticationTicket.

I have tried adding Claims to authenticated user's ClaimsIdentity in ClaimsPrincipal but custom claims dont persist between requests when navigated between pages. Obviously the HttpContext is authenticated. I have resorted to loading user profile from Db every time, which is slow.

How do I go about it? Any suggestions/ links would be appreciated. Thanks.